# Хочу выровнять текст по центру изображения

Tags: android

[image: По центру этих двух изображения хочу разместить два текста , но никак не получается]

По центру этих двух изображения хочу разместить два текста , но никак не получается

Comment: Делай Layout, картинку ставь как background к нему. Потом туда текст

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще с учетом отсутствия вашей разметки довольно сложно помочь, поэтому могу только предложить свою реализацию того что вам нужно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

это самый простой и быстрый вариант, вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно чтобы текст был поверх картинки (допускаю что с формулировкой могли быть проблемы):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myImageViewText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/myImageView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myImageView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView1"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

и вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

второй вариант реализации выравнивания по отношению центра картинки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="Some text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/imgView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/firstLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="Some text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/imgView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

результат опять такой же как и в первом случае, но такой вариант менее удобен на мой взгляд потому что нужно примеряться к картинке для марджина. И третий вариант:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="Some text" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:text="Some text" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Так же если вам нужно установить картинку как фон то можно воспользоваться тегом:

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
```

вот пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</LinearLayout>
```

Впредь будет две просьбы:

1. Метка `android-studio` должна использоваться только если вопросом связан с самой IDE (проблемы, неясности, сложности) и не нужно ее лепить везде где есть `android`
2. Постарайтесь задавать более развернутые вопросы, если вам он понятен это не значит что всем остальным тоже. Вы предоставили только картинку, но почему вы решили что у всех кто будет смотреть ваш вопрос автоматически появится на ПК ваша разметка и информация о том что вам нужно.